# Is it possible to custom Event Date format?

Tags: 7, datetime

On the Drupal 7 Upcoming Event, I would like to show the Event Date with abbreviated "Day, Month date, Year - Time". However, There an option that I like, which is "Fri, Mar 28, 2014 @ 4:55pm", but it contained with the "@" symbol. Is there a way to custom this being "Fri, Mar 28, 2014 - 4:55pm"?

PS: I know there is a way to add new date type, by going to "Administration/Configuration/Regional and Language". But none of them work like the way I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new date/time format by going to Administration > Configuration > Regional and Language > Date and Time. In the upper right corner of the screen you see two tabs: Types & Formats. First go to Formats and add your desired date format there (according to [PHP date formatting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)). In your case, this will probably be something like

```
D, M j, Y - g:i a
```

Next, you go to Types and create a new date type. You can assign your custom date format to this new date type.